# How to pass Image Bitmap to Tensorflow Mobile model?

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-bitmap

I have created a model in `Keras` using `Transfer Learning`.
I used `InceptionV3` model as `base` and made initial `52` layers as `non-trainable`.
Then I add my `custom` layers on top of it.
Trained it and saved to `hdf5` file.
The model predicted `A.png` on my `laptop`. `Correct`

I converted it to `pb` file using a `Github` tool.
Then I predicted `A.png` by `pb` model on `laptop`. It was `correct`.

Then I moved `pb` file to `android asset` folder.
I add `Tensorflow Mobile` dependency on it (not `TensorflowLite`).
I also added the same `A.png` to `asset`.
I loaded the model and pass `A.png` to `pb` model.
Output was `wrong` class.
I tried with other images. Always it points to the `same wrong class`.
`Output never changed`.

So I feel the `hdf5` , `pb` model are correct but there is some `mistake` in my `code which is passing the A.png to pb model`. Please help me!

`resized_image` -> Bitmap of A.png
`inferenceInterface` -> tensorflow model interface
`INPUT_NODE` -> name of input node
`OUTPUT_NODE` -> name of output node
`1,128,128,3` -> image is 128x128 and 3 channels

```
imageValuesFloat = normalizeBitmap(resized_image,128,127.5f,1.0f);
              inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE,imageValuesFloat,1,128,128,3);

inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);

//declare array to hold results obtained from model
float[] result = new float[OUTPUT_SIZE];

//copy the output into the result array
inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE,result);
```

Here is the `normalizeBitmap` function

```
public float[] normalizeBitmap(Bitmap source,int size,float mean,float std){
        float[] output = new float[size * size * 3];
        int[] intValues = new int[source.getHeight() * source.getWidth()];
        source.getPixels(intValues, 0, source.getWidth(), 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
            final int val = intValues[i];
            output[i * 3] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - mean)/std;
            output[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - mean)/std;
            output[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF) - mean)/std;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Normalization means bringing up the values between 0 and 1. What you are doing is standardization in which the values have a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1.

Comment: Actually I did not know much about android tensorflow. I know about keras.

Comment: I copied the code from https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/deploying-pytorch-and-keras-models-to-android-with-tensorflow-mobile-a16a1fb83f2

Comment: Meanwhile I saw another sample example on github. They used 128.5 and 128 as mean and std deviation. I used the same values and it solved the problem

Comment: can you tell me why changing the values solved the problem

Comment: Images ( colored ) have 3 channels namely R , G , B in which each of them has a value ranging between 0 and 255. In order to bring the images between the scale 0 to 1, each of the values are divided by 255. For normalization you can refer [here](https://link.medium.com/1tg6wdpx3V). Standardization is also a good practice. You can see [here](https://link.medium.com/64rMQnvx3V).

Comment: for standardization you use numpy in python. How about in android to find the mean and std deviation?